# Change/Add control's objects from a static member

Tags: wpf, visual-studio-2010, xaml, controls

I've created a control with `DependencyProperty`. I need to change control's appearance when this property changes (even in design time). So, if properties is easy enough I can make bindings to them in XAML.
But in my case I need to change and add another `objects/controls` to it. I know about `PropertyChangedCallback` method, but it's a static method so I can't access to control's layout.

Any ideas?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to use PropertyChangedCallBack](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5498517/how-to-use-propertychangedcallback)

Comment: PropertyChangedCallback accepts 2 arguments, the first one is the actual sender (your control).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually you can get access to your control within `PropertyChangedCallback`. Just cast sender to your control an do whatever you want(adding/deleting and so on).

Comment: I've got a problem... I've created a PropertyChangedCallback method but I can't catch it. So, I even can't see what type is the sender and so on. How can I debug my static PropertyChangedCallback method?

Comment: @ArtemMakarov  If in debug mode it does not get into callback method means that certainly there is a problem with binding and property does not changes at all.